# Socket issue c# client to java server

Tags: java, c#, sockets

This is my problem, all the messages sent from the c# client aren't received by the server until that I Shutdown the socket on client side and finally the server receive all data in once time.

c# client side

```
public static class AsynchronousClient
{
    // The port number for the remote device.
    private const int port = 8888;

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public static Socket client;
    // The response from the remote device.
    private static String response = String.Empty;

    public static void StartClient()
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            // The name of the 
            // remote device is "host.contoso.com".
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8888);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            Send(client, "test connection");    
            sentDown.WaitOne();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), null);
    }

    public static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Java server side

```
public class Connection_to_port extends Thread {

  final static int port = 8888;
  private Socket socket;
  String message = "";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      ServerSocket socketServeur = new ServerSocket(port);
      while (true) {
        Socket socketClient = socketServeur.accept();
        Connection_to_port t = new Connection_to_port(socketClient);
        t.start();
        System.out.println("Connected to client : " + socketClient.getInetAddress());
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public Connection_to_port(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
  }

  public void run() {
    handleMessage();
  }

  public void handleMessage() {
    try {
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      message = in.readLine();
      System.out.println(message);
   }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my client i have to send some data to the server like that

```
AsynchronousClient.Send(AsynchronousClient.client, "{myjsondata}");
```

My client is just for sending, not receive.

The problem is, my java server receive nothing ! But the client said it's sent, and i see on Wireshark that's it's send.

When i do
    AsynchronousClient.client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

Finally i see all my message on the server at the same time. Like if i sent only one message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java side is trying to read a line (you are using `readLine`).

This method will not return until either there is an end-of-line character, or the stream is closed.

When you shutdown the client, in effect, the stream closes.

Your test message does not include an end-of-line character, so the only way for `readLine` to return is at the end of stream.

Comment: Thanks it works, so add \n is the better way or maybe someting better than readLine for handle message from client ?

Comment: If your messages are plain text, end-of-line is a good option. If the messages need to be something else, you have other options. For a fixed-length record of N bytes, read N bytes from the stream. It all depends on what you want to send.

Answer (score 1):

When you write to a socket, the message does not sent, it's saved in buffer until:

- Buffer is full
- You request to clean/flush the buffer
- You shutdown.

Try the following methods:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname.aspx
- http://angrez.blogspot.co.il/2007/02/flush-socket-in-net-or-c.html

Comment: That's not solve my problem but it's an interesting answer +1.